# Why noreturn/__builtin_unreachable prevents tail call optimization

Tags: c++, c, noreturn

I have come to fact that all major compilers will not do tail call optimization if a called function does not return (i.e. marked as `_Noreturn`/`[[noreturn]]` or there is a `__builtin_unreachable()` after the call). Is this an intended behavior and not a missed optimization, and if so why?

Example 1:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NORETURN _Noreturn
#else
#define NORETURN [[noreturn]]
#endif

void canret(void);
NORETURN void noret(void);

void foo(void) { canret(); }
void bar(void) { noret(); }
```

C:   https://godbolt.org/z/pJfEe-
C++: https://godbolt.org/z/-4c78K

Example 2:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define UNREACHABLE __assume(0)
#else
#define UNREACHABLE __builtin_unreachable()
#endif

void f(void);

void foo(void) { f(); }
void bar(void) { f(); UNREACHABLE; }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/PFhWKR

Comment: Can you describe a case where this matters? Is it about performance or code size?

Comment: I was investigating `boost::variant` switch visitation code bloat and came to the issue https://godbolt.org/z/c__MxS. Clang goes mad and puts stack adjustment in every branch if you have noreturn call somewhere. https://godbolt.org/z/PR6RMn GCC will make the same if it sees `abort`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's intentional, though perhaps controversial since it can seriously harm stack usage properties; for this reason I've even resorted to tricking the compiler to think a function that can't return can. The reasoning is that many noreturn functions are `abort`-like (or even call `abort`), and that it's likely someone running a debugger wants to be able to see where the call happened from -- information which would be lost by a tail call.

Citations:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10837
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56165
- https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67327
- etc.

Comment: If someone wanted to monitor an `abort`, wouldn't they also likely disable optimizations? Disabling an optimization for traceability in an optimized build seems counter productive. Asking for optimization typically implies that you won't be trying to debug. Or at least that you consider optimizations more important than traceability.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: No. This is a myth that presumably comes from MSVC culture where "debug build" meant debugging on, optimization off. Personally I find `-O0` code undebuggable. There's so much useless cruft spilling and reloading registers I can't tell what's going on, and single-stepping through anything takes forever. Modern debugging tools work fine with optimization, and oftentimes you end up having to debug with optimization on even if you don't want to, because your bug is UB whose effects change or disappear when you build without optimization.

Comment: This makes sense. Is this a factual information or opinion-based?

Comment: I also was thinking that it is because of `abort`/`std::terminate`, but it is too unreasonably to disable the tail call optimization for every noreturn function call.

Comment: Can you provide some corroborating evidence for this? Because I also find the idea that you will disable optimizations to support potential `abort()` call counter intuitive.

Comment: @SergeyA: Updated with citations.

Comment: Much obliged. Thx for sharing.